# R1C1 format with negative row reference results in #REF! error in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

This formula in VBA:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-6]=""ADD"",CONCATENATE(""QUIET "",RC[-6],"" "",RC[-5],"" "",RC[-4],"" "",RC[-3],"" "",RC[-2]),IF(RC[-6]=""DEL"",CONCATENATE(""QUIET "",RC[-6],"" "",RC[-5],"" "",RC[-4]),IF(OR(**R[-1]C[-6]**=""ADD"",**R[-1]C[-6]**=""DEL""),""//FacultyAG   EOJ"","""")))"
```

Results in this formula in cell:

```
=IF(RC[-6]="ADD",CONCATENATE("QUIET ",RC[-6]," ",RC[-5]," ",RC[-4]," ",RC[-3]," ",RC[-2]),IF(RC[-6]="DEL",CONCATENATE("QUIET ",RC[-6]," ",RC[-5]," ",RC[-4]),IF(OR(**#REF!**="ADD",**#REF!**="DEL"),"//FacultyAG   EOJ","")))
```

I can manually modify the forumla (relative addressing "on") and it works.  But whenever VBA puts the formual in, I get these #REF! errors.  It seems to be these -6 row references.  (-6 is a valid column ("1").)

Comment: Are you sure the active cell is not in row 1? Do you move the data around after the formula is placed?  Do you delete rows after the formula is placed?

Comment: You're definitely not putting the formula into row 1?  (i.e trying to refer to row 0?)

Comment: I should have said:I can manually modify the forumla (relative addressing "on") and it works. But whenever VBA puts the formual in, I get these #REF! errors. It seems to be these -6 column references. (-6 is a valid column ("1").)  Formula is in column 7.  Column 1, when relative addressing is on is column A.   I do not move or delete columns, rows or cells after formula is placed.

Comment: What specific cell are you looking at when you see the `#REF!` ?

Comment: It is one row up, six columns left.  Column 1 ("A"). The formula is copied by VBA in the same column and several rows, beginning in row 2.

Comment: It seems to me the problem is not the column but the row. The other column references are fine it is o my when you reference the row above that you get the error.

Comment: What is the location of `ActiveCell` when the VBA code is executing?  (To find out, insert a `MsgBox ActiveCell.Address` immediately before the line setting the formula.)

Comment: ActiveCell.Address is $G$1.  I stand corrected.  After I insert the formula I insert a row at row1.

Comment: Bingo - `G1` less one row and less 6 columns is `A0` - which is invalid.

Comment: I betcha that is it!  Let me modify my code by inserting the row first, then the formula.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: Thank you YowE3K!  That was the problem!  I moved my insert above my formula setting.  Worked as expected!

Comment: Comments are prone to deletion so I'll post an actual "answer" to the problem now.  (Unless Scott beats me to it - his original comment beat mine by 4 seconds!  :-)  And we both had the identical thoughts.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you are inserting the formula into a cell in row 1.

`R[-1]C[-6]` refers to the cell one row above and 6 cells to the left of the cell in which the formula is placed so, when the formula is placed into row 1, that means it is referring to a cell in row zero, which is invalid.  This causes a `#REF!` error and, even if you move the cell down (by, for instance, inserting a header row above it), the `#REF!` can't be corrected as Excel no longer knows what it was meant to be saying.

The solution is to ensure that the cell into which you are originally placing your formula is a cell where the formula will actually be valid.